# Font awesome <i></i> tag converted into <svg></svg>and onclick jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using font awesome 6. Font awesome converted `<i>` into `<svg>` and jQuery onclick function is not working.

```
<i class="fas fa-star star-light star-light submit_star mr-1 nnn" id="submit_star_3" data-rating="3"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star star-light star-light submit_star mr-1 nnn" id="submit_star_4" data-rating="4"></i>

<script>
$(document).on('click', '.submit_star', function() {
    rating_data = $(this).data('rating');   
});
</script>
```

Comment: I‘d recommend to put the icons inside buttons and attach the click listener to the buttons instead. Should also be better for accessibility since buttons are meant to be clickable, <i> tags are not.

Answer (score 0):

As @EinLinuus already pointed out – better wrap your icon in a parent element like `<button>`.

Your code doesn't work since fontAwesome will replace the DOM node.
So the replaced icon element won't be bound to your click event anymore.

#### Example 1: click event parent element

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  $('.fa-icon-wrap').on('click', function() {
    let rating_data = $(this).find('.fa-star').data('rating');
    alert('rating: ' + rating_data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="fa-icon-wrap"><i class="fas fa-star star-light star-light submit_star mr-1 nnn" id="submit_star_3" data-rating="3"></i></button>
<button class="fa-icon-wrap"><i class="fas fa-star star-light star-light submit_star mr-1 nnn" id="submit_star_4" data-rating="4"></i></button>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-8pHNiqTlsrRjVD4A/3va++W1sMbUHwWxxRPWNyVlql3T+Hgfd81Qc6FC5WMXDC+tSauxxzp1tgiAvSKFu1qIlA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

#### Example 2: add click event after DOM change

Using a [Mutation Observer.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
let outerWrap = document.querySelector('.content');
let options = {
  childList: true
};

let observer = new MutationObserver(mCallback);
function mCallback(mutations) {
  for (let mutation of mutations) {
    //add event listener after DOm change
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('Mutation Detected: A child node has been added or removed.');
    }
  }
  if(mutations.length){
      $('.fa-star').on('click', function (e) { 
        let rating_data = $(this).data('rating');   
        alert('rating: '+ rating_data);
      });
  }
  observer.disconnect();
}

observer.observe(outerWrap, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<i class="fas fa-star star-light star-light submit_star mr-1 nnn" id="submit_star_3" data-rating="3"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star star-light star-light submit_star mr-1 nnn" id="submit_star_4" data-rating="4"></i>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-8pHNiqTlsrRjVD4A/3va++W1sMbUHwWxxRPWNyVlql3T+Hgfd81Qc6FC5WMXDC+tSauxxzp1tgiAvSKFu1qIlA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```